# Plot graph with the data showing respective colors

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, colors

```
color = []
for key,value in ms.iterrows():
    if(value['Color']=='Blue'):
       color.append('b')
    elif(value['Color']=='Green'):
       color.append('g')
    elif(value['Color']=='Red'):
       color.append('r')
    elif(value['Color']=='Yellow'):
       color.append('y')
    elif(value['Color']=='Orange'):
       color.append('o')
    else:
       color.append('k')
ax =ms[['Height','Color']].plot(x='Color', kind='bar', title="Correlation", 
figsize=(15,10), color=color legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Colors", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Height", fontsize=12)
```

[image: Data]

[image: Graph]

My intention is to plot a bar graph that shows Color against Height. I managed to do it. However, I would like each of the bars to show respective color. In accord with the data set, I would like the 1st bar to show red...and so on. I tried adding the color, but it still shows only 1 color.

Comment: If the duplicate does not help here, please at least show in how far the `color` argument does not work for you.

Comment: I have added the color section to the existing problem, but it still shows the same outcome. No change in color for the bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to create a multicolumn dataframe and use the `stacked=True` option.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Height" : [5,3,6,4],
                   "Color" : ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]})

color = []
for key,value in df.iterrows():
    if(value['Color']=='Blue'):
       color.append('b')
    elif(value['Color']=='Green'):
       color.append('g')
    elif(value['Color']=='Red'):
       color.append('r')
    elif(value['Color']=='Yellow'):
       color.append('y')
    elif(value['Color']=='Orange'):
       color.append('o')
    else:
       color.append('k')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df["Height"]), columns=df["Color"], index=df["Color"])
ax = df2.plot(kind='bar', title="Correlation", color=color, legend=True, 
              fontsize=12, stacked=True)
ax.set_xlabel("Colors", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Height", fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create if/else conditions:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Height" : [5,3,6,4],
                   "Color" : ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]})

df.set_index('Color').Height.plot(kind='bar',color=df.Color)
```

[image]